# how split the array and save to database?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I parsed a file using `smarter_csv`:

```
file = SmarterCSV.process(smarter_csv, file_encoding: windows-1251', col_sep: ';', verbose: true, convert_values_to_numeric: true, remove_zero_values: false)
```

And got this array:

```
[{:code=>"1", :Name=>"Pen"},
 {:code=>"2", :Name=>"Apple"}]
```

how you can break this array to save it in the database?

I guess you need to iterate through items using `each`

Comment: Describe the model in which those values would be saved

Comment: I'm using gem activerecord. Model is empty. 

`class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

end`

Comment: Seems to me that you don't know much rails. I'll recommend you to read the Rails Guides. For you specific problem, take a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create

Comment: could you tell me the direction, I'm new to ruby/Sinatra.

Comment: I just did. Take a look at the link. If you can't really figure it out with it, You should take a step back and take a look at ruby basics, specially in the Enumerable methods: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Product model and attributes are code:string and name:string. And you store the parsed results in data variable.

You need to do the following:

```
data = [{:code=>"1", :name=>"Pen"},
 {:code=>"2", :name=>"Apple"}]

data.each{|row| Product.create(row) }
```

This will create two entries in your Product model.